# Codeigniter Session is not storing values when i redirect from login page to dashboard page

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

We have developed school admission system, in that we store user id when user logs in the system, and then we redirect the user to dashboard page and in dashboard page we fetch values from user id this system works perfectly fine under my localhost but problem is on when i host on live server,

on live server when user logs in the system then user id getting stored in the session on login page (when i print values of session it displays id of user) but when it redirects to dashboard that value gets deleted,

see my login page code

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('Login_v');
    }
    public function Login_user()
    {
        $uname=$_POST['username'];
        $pwd=$_POST['password'];
        $this->load->model('Login_m');
        $data=$this->Login_m->get_user($uname,$pwd);
        $this->load->library('session');
        if($data!=NULL)
        {
           $id=$data[0]->sid;
           $sdata=array('sid' => $id);
           $this->session->set_userdata($sdata);
                /* echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                window.location = "http://cmsgroupnigdi.com/admission/dashboard"
                </script>';*/
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                window.location = "http://localhost/admission/dashboard"
                </script>';
            exit();
        } else {
            $data="Invalid Login Details";
            $this->load->view('Login_v',['data'=>$data]);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This is my session array on login page when i print it

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1511755625 [sid] => 1 )
```

and on dashboard page when i print it

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1511755625)
```

**Session/Cookie $config - application/config.php**

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
$config['cookie_domain'] = '.cmsgroupnigdi.com/admission/';;
$config['cookie_path'] = '/';
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Check you `$config['cookie_domain']` on config.php

Comment: $config['cookie_domain'] = '';

Comment: Well then take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19024706/2131856

Comment: i tried but same happens

Comment: what if i replace session code with cookie means storing user id in cookies

Comment: What are your session settings in the config.php?

Comment: this are my session and cookie settings

Comment: $config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;


$config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
$config['cookie_domain'] = '.http://www.cmsgroupnigdi.com/admission/';
$config['cookie_path'] = '/';
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysteriously your code works... with some changes.
You still need to add in validation and other things, but this is more an exercise in debugging.

I did alter some things - Read through the code - to prevent some of your possible "next questions."

What I did was create a mock up of your script with added debugging.

So your "login" controller - **Login.php**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $this->load->model('login_m');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('login_v');
    }

    public function Login_user() {
        // Debug - View Posted Data
        var_dump($_POST);

        // @todo Requires Validation
        $uname = $_POST['username'];
        $pwd = $_POST['password'];
        $data = $this->login_m->get_user($uname, $pwd);

        // Debug - Data from Model
        var_dump($data);

        if ($data != NULL) {
            $id = $data[0]->sid;
            $sdata = array('sid' => $id);
            $this->session->set_userdata($sdata);

            // Debug - View The Session data
            var_dump($this->session->userdata);
            // exit required to view the var_dump outputs
            // in this method so prevent the redirect
            // Comment it out to allow the redirect
            //exit();

            redirect("admission/dashboard");
            exit();
        } else {
            // Debug - View The Session data
            var_dump($this->session->userdata);

            $error_message = "Invalid Login Details";
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message',$error_message);
            redirect('login',$data);
        }

    }
}
```

The dummy model - **Login_m.php**

```
class Login_m extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Simulate a good and bad login.
     */
    public function get_user($uname, $pwd) {

        // use for successful login testing
        $return_array[]= (object)array('sid'=>1);

        // use for failed login testing
        $return_array = NULL;

        return $return_array;
    }
}
```

And the View - **login_v.php** ( Note: I made it lowercase )

```
<h2>This is the Login View</h2>
<?php
// $error_message isn't always passed in so we need to cater for that
$error_message = $this->session->flashdata('error_message');

if ( ! empty($error_message)): ?>
    <div>
        <p> <?= $error_message; ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<form action="login/login_user" method="POST">
    <label>username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="">
    <br>
    <label>password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="check_login" value="Login">
</form>
```

There are many ways to do this. As noted, you need to perform validation etc but this is something to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a session variable. Here I am using **admin** as session variable

In your **login Page**

```
$this->session->set_userdata('admin', $data);
```

instead of `window.location` you can use `redirect()`

```
redirect('admission/dashboard');
```

In your **dashboard page**

```
$admindata   = $this->session->userdata('admin');
print_r($admindata);
```

Comment: on login page it displays values in session but not on dashboard page

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the session library just for login function. Try loading the session in the autoload.php file under config folder to get access everywhere in the system. Maybe that is the reason why you are unable to access.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, probably check with your **PHP version** . Intially was using PHP version 7.1 and session was not working, was facing the same issue. After that when i changed to **PHP version 7.0** it worked well.

If you could mention the **PHP version** what you are using. It would be helpful to solve.

If not please try to change your code igniter **SYSTEM**  folder with recent version. Possibly it would solve your issue. They have fixed some bugs regarding session.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you, all of you for giving excellent suggestions i solved the problem i  use vanilla php session library. thanks a lot